# svn update from php file

Tags: php, linux, svn

I have two server, I wanted to do a script for svn update my project.
The server A is my production server where I try to update svn from php.

My server B is my developement server.

---

1 . My script on my server B work fine :

```
$projet = $_POST['data'];
exec('ssh user@myserver "echo myPassword | sudo -S ./svnup.sh '.$projet.'"',$out,$ret);
```

=> It's ok.

---

2 . I make a script on my server A for update directly from internet (my server B is local) :

```
$projet = $_POST['data'];
exec('sudo -S ./svnup.sh $project',$out);
var_dump($out[0]); 
die;
```

=> It doesn't work, The response = NULL

---

Thanks by advance if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the user which actually runs the command. In your first example it is "user", in your second example it is webserver ("apache" or "nobody" depending on host config). Usually webserver lacks privileges to write and so svn update fails.

No one prohibits you to use your example from server B directly on server A. In effect you will authenticate as "user" who has relevant priveleges to run svn update even so it is called from the same server.